# 32bit Operating systems vs 64 bit operating system

Tags: operating-system, x86, 64-bit, benchmarking, 32bit-64bit

I want to ask that if 32 bit window7 and 64 bit window7 is installed on two PCs having same configurations (i.e processor, RAM, etc) then I run same program(i.e data compression) on both OS then which OS will compress the same amount of data more quickly?? or both will have the same speed to performing the tasks ??

Comment: You really need to read the FAQ about how to post here. But in general  if your computer isn't doing any paging then more memory will not make a huge difference. But two different operating systems never have the SAME speed.

Comment: It depends on the program also...  @@Request topic to be moved to SuperUser

Comment: 64-bit code tends to run a bit slower.  But data compression is an integer problem, you may get some mileage out of it handling 64-bit integers more efficiently.  Depends on the algorithm.  The simplest way to find out is to just try it, you don't need our help with that.

Comment: I'd contest that 64bit code runs slower, at least on x86. That's because it's quite a bit different from other 64bit architectures - the code footprint increase is rather small (compared to, say, Power/SPARC). Also, on x86, 64bit code is _more capable_ (more registers, in particular, and more instruction set extensions available to "generic" code) than "plain" 32bit, as well as better-performing default calling conventions. I'd like to know which benchmarks you refer to when you say "64bit code is slower" (at the very least when talking about x86).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the main question when choosing between 32 and 64 bits is not "my processor support 64 bits - should I use this because 64 is "twice better" than 32", but "how much memory do I have".

64-bit programs use about 50% more memory then their 32-bit counterparts. The results of this are:

less code/data can fit into processor caches -> more cache misses -> your super-fast processor waits more for memory controller to fetch data from RAM. Processor also needs to read more data because it's more bloated.

Once you're out of RAM and the system starts swapping - disk access is thousands times slower than RAM, so any potential benefits of 64-bit code are flying out of window.

On the other hand, in 64-bit mode processor has more registers, so it doesn't need to access memory that often, also, some calculations (64-bit numbers etc.) are more efficient. So generally, code which is not memory-restricted runs slightly faster in 64-bit mode.

So, if your system has, say, 2GiB of RAM or less then I would definitely choose 32 bits. More than 4GiB - the benefits of 64 bits are becoming more prominent. Around 4GiB is a "grey zone" - you need to make a choice yourself.

In short the speed of your program will depend on the memory you have.  based on the OS you installed

Comment: interesting response! ;)

Answer (score 0):

64-bit compression programs (WinRAR, WinZip, 7-Zip) run 5-10% faster than their 32-bit counterparts.

http://www.powerarchiver.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4867

In general 64-bit programs will have a slight speed boost over their 32-bit counterparts, in exchange for using more memory. This is because the size of the memory variables has doubled, but the efficiency of computations run in 64-bit mode by a 64-bit processor has gone up.

http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0003/

As a general rule of thumb: if you have a 64-bit operating system, install the 64-bit version of programs when they're available. All processors that come with new computers are 64-bit nowadays but surprisingly application developers are making the switch much more slowly.